# HOW To resolve : Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

After modify recipe with using my repo I have this error after rebuild.
How to resolve this ?
log:

```
ERROR: phosphor-user-manager-1.0+gitAUTOINC+5a6e836a71-r1  do_package: QA Issue: phosphor-user-manager: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:

  /dbus-1

  /usr/share

  /usr/share/phosphor-certificate-manager

  /usr/share/phosphor-certificate-manager/nslcd

  /dbus-1/system.d

  /dbus-1/system.d/phosphor-nslcd-cert-config.conf

  /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

  /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/phosphor-certificate-manager@nslcd.service

Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.

phosphor-user-manager: 8 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]

ERROR: phosphor-user-manager-1.0+gitAUTOINC+5a6e836a71-r1 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/openbmc/build/tmp/work/arm1176jzs-openbmc-linux-gnueabi/phosphor-user-manager/1.0+gitAUTOINC+5a6e836a71-r1/temp/log.do_package.224136

ERROR: Task (/home/openbmc/meta-phosphor/recipes-phosphor/users/phosphor-user-manager_git.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 17):

It is good to understand the problem and what causes it.

Every recipe in Yocto has its own `${WORKDIR}` path.

Under that path, Bitbake unpacks all `SRC_URI` entries of the recipe before starting to perform the next tasks such as configure, compile, ... etc.

Now, after getting the output you need to install it into your final `rootfs`.

The installation process is done in `do_install` task using the `${D}` variable.

`${D}` points to `${WORKDIR}/image`.

Let's say that your recipe compiles a `C` program which its output is `hello` binary.

Now, you install it to your rootfs under `/usr/bin` like:

```
do_install() {
   install -d ${D}${bindir}
   cp ${WORKDIR}/hello ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Now, after `do_install` is performed, the `${D}${bindir}` will contain `hello`

After that, the package process `do_package` will take what is inside `${D}/usr/bin` and add it to the final recipe package which is the `package` directory inside `${WORKDIR}`.

Now, the problem will occur.

The package process will only take what is in the `FILES` variable that is related to the recipe, more info about `FILES` [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-FILES).

If it finds that some content present in `${D}` folder that is not specified in `FILES_${PN}` it will give that error.

So, in order to fix the issue, you just need to add all content of `${D}` to `FILES_${PN}` variable.

In addition, you can specify types of packages (`dbg`, `doc`, `dev`, `ptest`, ...).

***Example***: If your recipe provides a binary file, a `man` document and a library files, you can organize it like this:

```
do_install(){
   install -d ${D}${bindir}
   install -d ${D}/usr/include/helloLib
   install -d ${D}/usr/share/man/man1/

   cp ${WORKDIR}/build/hello ${D}${bindir}
   cp ${WORKDIR}/build/lib_files ${D}/usr/include/helloLib
   cp ${WORKDIR}/doc/hello.1 ${D}/usr/share/man/man1
}
```

For `${bindir}` and other appropriate paths variable, check [this](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/conf/bitbake.conf?h=purple).

Now, our `image` folder which is `${D}` contains:

- /usr/bin/hello
- /usr/include/helloLib/hello_lib.h (or many others)
- /usr/share/man/man1/hello.1

You can specify them all to `FILES_${PN}` like this:

```
FILES_${PN} = "/usr/bin/* /usr/include/helloLib/* /usr/share/*"
```

or:

```
FILES_${PN}-doc = "/usr/share/man/man1/*"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "/usr/inlcude/helloLib/*"
FILES_${PN}     = "/usr/bin/*"
```

After collecting all specified items from `FILES` into the `package` folder, a package type process will start according to your `PACKAGE_CLASSES` variable that can be `package_rpm`, `package_deb`, `package_tar` or `package_ipk`, more info [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_CLASSES).

Finally, let's understand how the final image is collected.

The `image` recipe performs `do_rootfs` which will create the final rootfs of your system.

It goes through all recipes that are in `IMAGE_INSTALL` , `IMAGE_FEATURES` , .. etc and enter the `${WORKDIR}` directory for each one of them, and collects all created packages, and install them into the final rootfs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped me to better understand to this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the new version of Yocto this will help: `FILES:${PN} ="name"` of the dirs not shipping"; In old versions, it is `FILES_${PN}`.

So your answer should be:
`FILES:${PN}= "/dbus-1 /usr/share /lib/systemd/"`