# error files are installed but cannot be shipped with packages

Tags: qt, yocto, qmake

I am using **Yocto** Build system to build my Linux distribution.

I am using **Qt C++** to develop my application. I have one file which has to be part of my package which I will send after my build.

I have deployed the file in Target device with help of **qmake**. I don't want to change anything in **bitbake** file.

Is this possible or not?

I tried:

```
INSTALLS += target
```

the error I get is:

```
files are installed but cannot be shipped with packages
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install something in the `do_install` step, you must specify the files which are installed in the [FILES_${PN}](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=files+var#term-FILES) variable.

For example...

```
do_install() {
    cat <<EOF > ${bindir}/hello.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello world
EOF
    chmod +x ${bindir}/hello.sh
}

...

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/hello.sh"
```

You may need to use the `:append` qualifier if your recipe inherits from some class.

[See also...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542598/how-to-resolve-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any-package)